# Why can't I vote to delete/undelete some posts?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

Having just got access to the 10k tools (yippee!), I've been reading the help and trying to figure out what I should/shouldn't be doing. It all seems pretty much straightforward but there's one thing I don't understand.

On the Delete tab, there are some posts greyed out and a tooltip that says "you can't vote to delete/undelete this post" (see below):

[image: screenshot]

It's not obvious to me what the difference is between the posts I *can* vote on and the posts I *can't* vote on.

Would someone be kind enough to enlighten me? I don't see why I should be shown posts that I can't vote on.

Comment: You can "faster" delete posts having 20k+ rep. That may be the issue with those posts.

Comment: +1 I'm a 10k noob and I agree the delete/undelete rules aren't very clear.

Comment: Undeletion is restricted when a diamond mod deletes a post.  It can only be undeleted by a diamond mod.  For deletion, I believe it is only restricted based on the age of the post and score.  10Kers can only delete posts with a -3 score or worse, and can't delete something until it has been closed for 48 hours.  But it would be nice to get a complete answer in case there is something else I'm not aware of.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, I'd like an answer too - it does seem strange to show me those posts but then tell me I can't do anything with them. If it was just a few that wouldn't be so bad, but 90% of the posts are like this (at least at the time I looked at them).

Comment: @RogerRowland it is most likely the age.  There are enough 20K users (on SO) who start the ball rolling on deletion sooner than 48 hours, so posts do accummulate delete votes before a 10Ker can act.  Maybe there is a feature request there to hide them, or a good reason not to hide them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If something appears in the list of posts with delete votes but you can't vote on it, it's because either the post is no longer eligible for deletion (but it received votes when it was, so it's still in the list), or it's not eligible for deletion *by you*.

#### From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> 3. **Users with reputation >= 10k** (more precisely, the [“moderator tools” privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete *questions* that have been [closed/on-hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stack-overflow-how-do-they-work) for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; [more if the question is popular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), but ten votes at most.
>
> 4.  **Users with reputation >= 20k** (more precisely, the [“trusted user” privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools); 4k on beta sites) are not subject to the 48-hour waiting period for deleting closed questions with a score of -3 or lower. They may also delete *answers* of score -1 or lower. It takes three votes to delete an answer.

In your case, [the first post in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781431/msysgit-configuration-steps-issues/20798879#20798879) was an *answer* that had two delete votes from 20K+ users - so while your 10K allowed you to *see* it, you are not yet privileged enough to participate in its deletion.

For undelete, note that only moderators can undelete an answer if it was deleted *by* a moderator.

Comment: Any idea if there is a distinction between closed and on-hold? In other words, do the same rules in your answer apply to on-hold questions?

Comment: It [appears](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192176/162102) that 10k users can delete a question two days into the five-day "on hold" period.  I don't have a test case handy to experiment with, but I note that the question observing the behavior was asked by a member of the com team.

Comment: @chuex Monica is correct. An on-hold question *is* a closed question, it just has a different label for a little bit. So yes, they can delete an on-hold question.

Comment: @9Shogs, thanks for the big assist!

Comment: Thanks all - I'm still not quite sure why I need to be shown things that I can't take action on though. If it's normal and everyone just accepts it, I'm sure I can live with it :-)

Comment: @RogerRowland probably because filtering for what you can see would make the code more complex than the perceived benefit would call for.  (I, personally, would like it to somehow indicate to me which thigns in that list I've already voted on (I know I have a request for that here somewhere), and I'm assuming it's the same issue.)